# Community Toolkit Maui Popup Crashes When Clicking Outside

Tags: popup, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Community Toolkit Maui Popup crash when clicking outside of the dialog.
But this **happens only if the popup contains an Entry** control.

See the sample at GitHub:
https://github.com/HaimoHeymann/MauiTestApp

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: What exception causes the crash?  What does the stack trace show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click outside the popup you return a null and it is expecting an bool. So you get an

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

So your Event should look something like this by removing the explicit casting (bool):

```
private async void OnTestClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var popup = new PopupEdit("Title", "", "Apply", "Cancel");
    var result = await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
    if (result is bool boolResult)
    {
        if( boolResult)
        {
            lbResult.Text = popup.ResultString;
            return;
        }
    }

    lbResult.Text = "No Result";
}
```

If you do want to keep the explicit casting you can make it nullable like:

```
var result = (bool?)await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
```

Comment: correct, the issue was the 'result', your answer solved the problem, thanks